# How to can I search string from a large table in SQL Server using stored procedures in multiple times

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I want to store 200k+ products from an Excel file into SQL Server using a stored  procedure. I have two tables (`products`, `Inventory`)

Firstly I check the barcode of the product, if the product exists then get `ProductId` based on the barcode provided, and store `ProductId` in inventory.

With inventory detail but if no product found against barcode then create product  and then get `productId` save inventory with new `productId`.

The query is 100% working but take too much time to save all data.

This is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddProductsWithCat_Sp]
    @Category_Id int = 0,
    @ProductId int = 0,
    @ProductInvertory_Id int = 0,
    @Category_Name varchar(3000),
    @ProductName varchar(3000),
    @Brand_Name varchar(2000),
    @Barcode varchar(3000),
    @Description varchar(4000),
    @ProductInventory_UnitPrice decimal,
    @ProductInventory_Status bit,
    @Product_TotalPrice decimal,
    @ProductInventory_SellingPrice decimal,
    @ProductInventory_Qty int,
    @Brand_Name_Urdu varchar(3000),
    @Description_Urdu varchar(4000),
    @ProductName_Urdu varchar(3500),
    @Category_Name_Urdu varchar(2000)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CheckCategoryName varchar(200);
    DECLARE @CheckBarcode varchar(500);

    SET @CheckBarcode = (SELECT pp.ProductId FROM Products pp WHERE pp.Barcode LIKE '%@Barcode%');
    SET @CheckCategoryName = (SELECT c.Category_Id FROM Categories c WHERE c.Category_Name = @Category_Name);

    IF (@CheckCategoryName IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Categories (Category_Name, Category_Name_Urdu, Status)
        VALUES (@Category_Name, @Category_Name_Urdu, 1);

        SET @CheckCategoryName = (SELECT MAX(cc.Category_Id) FROM Categories cc);
    END;

IF (@CheckBarcode is Null)
Begin 
insert into Products(ProductName,Barcode,Description,Status,DateTime,Brand_Name,Category_Id,ProductImage,Brand_Name_Urdu,Description_Urdu,ProductName_Urdu)
values(@ProductName,@Barcode,@Description,1,GETDATE(),@Brand_Name,@CheckCategoryName,'no Image',@Brand_Name_Urdu,@Description_Urdu,@ProductName_Urdu);

set @CheckBarcode=(select MAX(pp.ProductId) from Products pp);
END;
insert into ProductInventories(ProductId,ProductInventory_UnitPrice,ProductInventory_SellingPrice,ProductInventory_Qty,ProductInventory_Status,DateTime,Product_TotalPrice)
Values(@CheckBarcode,@ProductInventory_UnitPrice,@ProductInventory_SellingPrice,@ProductInventory_Qty,1,GETDATE(),@Product_TotalPrice)

  END
```

Comment: maybe you can limit the procedure work, therefore, you can get rid of timeout

Comment: Hmm, try to do some bulk insert into a (temporary) staging table (variable) of all the data you want to upload. Then try to process that using set based logic, not row by row as you're currently do.